# Beispiele für Konsonanten, die zwischen Artikel und Wort gewandert sind

Tags: contractions

Aus dem Englischen kenne ich das Phänomen, dass ein Konsonant zwischen Artikel und Wort wandern kann.

So heißt etwa "Natter" im Englischen "adder", weil "an adder" und "a nadder" eine derartige Verschiebung leicht ermöglicht.

Im Deutschen ist mir dieses Phänomen nur im Dialekt bekannt.

> Wie nennt man dieses Phänomen?
>
> Kennt ihr Beispiele im Deutschen?

Off-Topic Bonusfrage: Etwaige Beispiele in anderen Sprachen würden mich auch interessieren und könnten zumindest im Kommentar angemerkt werden.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juncture_loss

Comment: interessant. Ich kenne leider keine. allerdings hohe Poll Gefahr!

Comment: Diese Art von Wortspiel gibt es auch Im Französischen.    *(l'amoralité/la moralité) de cet homme me sidère* ist (in  mündlicher Kommunikation) zweideutig. Es kann entweder als *Die Amoralitat dieses Mannes verblüfft mich* gehört werden  oder als das Gegenteil *Die Moralitat dieses Mannes verblüfft mich*

Comment: @Samuel Was ist die Gefahr? Ich verstehe "Poll Gefahr" nicht.

Comment: @thei ist sogar ein der falsche Ausdruck, die Gefahr ist, dass es zu einer Sammlung wird und jeder ein Beispiel postet. Solche Fragen & Antworten sollten wir vermeiden.

Comment: @Samuel: Nachdem ich dieses Phänomen im Englischen und im Dialekt seit Jahren kenne und trotzdem keine deutschen Beispiele kenne, besteht diese Gefahr überhaupt nicht. Darüberhinaus wäre die Reaktion auf diese Gefahr nicht notwendigerweise die Vermeidung der Frage, sondern Community wiki.

Comment: @thei eben nicht, bitte nicht. Community wikis sollten so selten wie möglich gemacht werden (müssen). Besser sind Fragen die lange Antworten herausfordern und dadurch die Anzahl der Antworten einschränken. Außerdem stellst du zwei Fragen, weswegen eigentlich jede Antwort die nur eine Frage beantwortet "falsch" ist.

Comment: @Samuel: Bitte eröffne doch einen Metathread darüber, warum diese Frage hier schlecht ist. Ich möchte deutsche Beispiele und - failing that - einen grammatischen Begriff dafür, der dann zumindest die weitere Suche ermöglicht. Ich finde es nicht sehr günstig, allgemeine Richtlinien als Argument im Einzelfall zu verwenden. Ich wiederhole, dass bei dieser Frage keinerlei Gefahr für zuviele Antworten besteht. (Und dass Ressourcenlisten eben kein Übel in sich sind, aber das ist ein anderes Thema.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: de] Dieser morphologische Prozess heißt angesichts des Englischen *juncture loss*, etwa *Verbindungsstellenverlust*.

Es ist durchaus unwahrscheinlicher, dass das im (Hoch)deutschen vorkommen könnte. Wörter werden in der Regel nicht wie im Englischen miteinander ausgesprochen - man hört eine knappe Pause zwischen 'eine' und 'Natter'. Hingegen würden 'a nadder' und 'an adder' ohne Betonung identisch ausgesprochen. Es besteht der Unterschied zwischen *a* und *an* nur zur Erleichterung der Aussprache — er bedeutet nichts — deshalb gibt es keinen Hinweis ob das /n/ zum Artikel oder Substantiv gehört.

Zudem gibt die Fallbeugung einen Hinweis — auch wenn 'eine Natter' als 'einen Atter' missverstanden würde, wäre 'einer Natter' (oder 'sie') eindeutig. 'Einen Atter' wäre eine unmögliche Interpretation im ersten Fall.

Es existieren im Deutschen trotzdem Lehnwörter wie *Orange*, die auf diese Weise umgewandelt worden sind - das ist aber schon im Französischen geschehen, bevor das Wort übernommen wurde, da *une norange* und *une orange* sich genau so wenig unterscheiden.

**Aha!** Es gibt wohl möglich doch ein Beispiel im Deutschen und zwar den alternativen Namen der Natter - **die Otter**.

Laut [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Otter&hidx=1):

> ²Otter f. ‘Schlange’; in der zoologischen Terminologie bezeichnet der Plural Ottern eine mit hochentwickeltem Giftapparat ausgestattete Unterfamilie der Vipern (s. Kreuzotter). Das von Luther mehrfach verwendete Otter ist entstanden aus älterem nō̌ter (15. Jh.), einer omd. Nebenform (mit Verdumpfung von a zu o) **von mhd. nāter(e) ‘Schlange’ (s. Natter), mit Aufgabe des anlautenden n-, das als Endung eines voraufgehenden unbestimmten Artikels empfunden wurde**.

---

[image: gb] This process, in respect of the English language, is called *juncture loss*.

It's much less likely that this could occur in (standard) German. In German, words are pronounced more distinctly - a slight pause is heard between 'eine' and 'Natter', whereas 'an adder' and 'a nadder' would be pronounced identically when unstressed. The difference between *a* and *an* exists only to ease pronunciation — it carries no meaning — so there is no indication whether the /n/ belongs to the article or to the noun.

Moreover case declination helps — even if it were misheard as 'einen Atter', 'einer Natter' would be unambiguous. 'Einen Atter' would be an impossible interpretation in the nominative.

There are some loan words in German, such as *Orange*, that have gone through such a change — but that had already happened in French, before the word was adopted, as *une norange* and *une orange* are equally confusable.

**Ah ha!** There is potentially an example of this in German after all: in fact it's an alternative name of the snake discussed - **die Otter**.

From [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Otter&hidx=1) (my translation):

> ²Otter f. ‘Snake’; [...] **from Middle High German nāter(e) ‘Snake’ (see Natter), with loss of the initial n-, which was perceived as the ending of a preceding indefinite article**.

Comment: Für sächliche Wörter ist das schon möglich (ein Nagel -> ein Agel), und ich würde eben nicht davon ausgehen, dass zu der Zeit, als adder und orange entstanden sind, im Deutschen Worte überall mit Pausen getrennt wurden. Und ja, "der Nagel" und "der Agel" würde verschieden klingen, das gilt aber auch für "the adder" und "the nadder", ich glaube, der Punkt ist, dass die Zweideutigkeit den Hörer an die mögliche Existenz des Wortes Agel gewöhnt, sodass es dann verstanden wird, sobald es jemand irrtümlich verwendet.

Comment: An den definitiven Artikel hab ich nicht gedacht - könnte sein dass man 'the' vor Wörten für Schlangen und Fruchten in der Alltagssprache komparativ selten sagt(e).

Comment: This slight pause you're refering to is called a glottal stop or "Glottisverschlusslaut", just thought I'd add the technical term for this.